# Trigger IIS recycle on file change other than web.config

Tags: iis, web-config

When setting up an ASP.NET web application using IIS 10, the web server observes the web.config file for changes by default. If the file changes, an automatic app pool recycle is triggered.

Is it possible to set up the IIS to recycle the app pool automatically as well if a specific other file is changed? And can it be located outside the web application's root path, e.g. its parent directory?

Comment: The basic mistake is that when `web.config` changes, IIS does not recycle but ASP.NET runtime reloads your web app.

Comment: Not only web.config, but also other files changed, application will reload. You can change  files in visual studio and publish again. The update will take effect immediately.